# Bjarne Stroustrup PPP - Chapter 9 Drill 4 - cout enum error

Tags: c++, enums

I am trying to solve Drill 4 of Bjarne Stroustrups Principles and Practice 2nd Edition. For some reason it won't let me cout the Month and Year members I initialized earlier. I know there are alternatives to using enumerators, but I would like to know how to do it using it. Can someone help me out there? Cheers

```
//  Philipp Siedler
//  Bjarne Stroustrup's PPP
//  Chapter 9 Drill 4

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

class Year {
    static const int min = 1800;
    static const int max = 2200;
private:
    int y;
public:
    class Invalid {};
    Year(int x) : y{ x } { if (x < min || max <= x) throw Invalid{}; };
    int year() { return y; };
};

enum class Month {
    jan = 1, feb, march, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec
};

class Date {
private:
    Year y;
    Month m;
    int d;
public:
    Date(Year y, Month m, int d) : y(y), m(m), d(d) {};
    Year year() { return Year{ y }; };
    Month month() { return Month{ m }; };
    int day() { return d; };
    void add_day(int n);
};

void Date::add_day(int n) {
    d += n;
}

int main()
try
{
    Date today{ Year{ 1978 }, Month::jun, 25 };
    Date tomorrow = today;

    tomorrow.add_day(1);

    cout << "Year: " << today.year() << " Month: " << today.month() << " Day: " << today.day() << "\n";
    cout << "Year: " << tomorrow.year() << " Month: " << tomorrow.month() << " Day: " << tomorrow.day() << "\n";

    keep_window_open();
}

catch (runtime_error e) {
    cout << e.what() << '\n';
    keep_window_open();
}
catch (...) {
    cout << "Exiting" << '\n';
    keep_window_open();
}
```

Comment: No `std::flush`ing?

Comment: I'm quiet new to coding and c++, have not touched on the topic of std::flush yet.

Comment: @Philipp Siedler  You have to overload the operator << for the enumeration or change the function month() such a way that it would return a string with the name of a month.

Comment: Looks wrong: `max <= max`

Comment: @JVApen yes that is true, thank you. But it's not the point I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I just figured it out myself, so who ever needs help with the same issue, here is a potential solution and an easy example of operator overloading:

```
//  Philipp Siedler
//  Bjarne Stroustrup's PPP
//  Chapter 9 Drill 4

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

class Date {
public:
    enum Month {
        jan = 1, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec
    };

    Date(int y, Month m, int d);
    void add_day(int n);

    int year() const { return y; }
    Month month() const { return m; }
    int day() const { return d; }

private:
    int y;
    Month m;
    int d;
};

Date::Date(int y0, Date::Month m0, int d0) {
    d = d0;
    m = m0;
    y = y0;
}

void Date::add_day(int n) {
    d += n;
}

static ostream & operator<< (ostream & os, const Date::Month & m) {
    switch (m) {
    case Date::jan: os << "January"; break;
    case Date::feb: os << "February"; break;
    case Date::mar: os << "March"; break;
    case Date::apr: os << "April"; break;
    case Date::may: os << "May"; break;
    case Date::jun: os << "June"; break;
    case Date::jul: os << "July"; break;
    case Date::aug: os << "August"; break;
    case Date::sep: os << "September"; break;
    case Date::oct: os << "October"; break;
    case Date::nov: os << "November"; break;
    case Date::dec: os << "December"; break;
    }
    return os;
}

ostream & operator<< (ostream & os, const Date & dd) {
    os << "Year: " << dd.year() << " Month: " << dd.month() << " Day: " << dd.day() << endl;
    return os;
}

int main()
try
{
    Date today{ 1978, Date::jun, 25 };
    Date tomorrow = today;
    tomorrow.add_day(1);

    cout << today;
    cout << tomorrow;

    keep_window_open();
}

catch (runtime_error e) {
    cout << e.what() << '\n';
    keep_window_open();
}
catch (...) {
    cout << "Exiting" << '\n';
    keep_window_open();
}
```